# Nuxt3, Supabase, fetching. Update datas with ref() to filter it

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, fetch, supabase, nuxt3

Please see my code below.

[And a photo attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shpgs.png)

After several days of research, I decided to ask for a little help.

I created buttons that change reactive variables => ref()(country_id and category_id)

These variables are used by my code to filter the data. If I change the variables manually everything works. Filter and fetch is ok.

On the other hand, the app does not refetch the data when the variables (ref) are updated by clicking on the buttons.

So I would like to find a way to automatically redo the fetch at each change. (By clicking on button or with watch().

Unfortunately I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

My template :

```js
<template>
    <div class="border-b mb-5 border-gray-200 pb-3 items-start sm:flex sm:items-center sm:justify-between">
        <div class="sm:w-0 sm:flex-1">
            <h1 id="message-heading" class="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Countries</h1>
            <p class="mt-1 mb-2 truncate text-sm text-teal-500">Filter jobs reserved for a country</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overflow-x-auto border-l-2 border-teal-200 scrollbar-hide sm:w-2/3">
            <div class="mt-3 flex sm:ml-4 sm:mt-0">
                <button
                    class="ml-3 h-min w-max inline-flex items-center rounded-full bg-teal-500 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-700 hover:ring-teal-700"
                    type="button" v-for="country in activeCountries" as="template" :key="country.id" :value="country"
                    @click="clickCountry(country.country_id)">
                    <p class="truncate">#{{ country.name }}</p>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border-b mb-5 border-gray-200 pb-3 items-start sm:flex sm:items-center sm:justify-between">
        <div class="sm:w-0 sm:flex-1">
            <h1 id="message-heading" class="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Jobs</h1>
            <p class="mt-1 mb-2 truncate text-sm text-teal-500">Filter jobs by skills</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overflow-x-auto border-l-2 border-teal-200 scrollbar-hide sm:w-2/3">
            <div class="mt-3 flex sm:ml-4 sm:mt-0">
                <button
                    class="ml-3 h-min w-max inline-flex items-center rounded-full bg-teal-500 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-700 hover:ring-teal-700"
                    type="button" v-for="category in categories" as="template" :key="category.id" :value="category"
                    @click="clickCategory(category.name)">
                    <p class="truncate">#{{ category.name }}</p>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-wrap">
        <div class="" key=" offer" v-for="  (offer, index) of offers  ">
            <div class="w-min h-min">
                <OfferCardArrow v-if="index === 0" v-bind="offer" />
            </div>
            <div class="w-min h-min">
                <OfferCard v-if="index !== 0" v-bind="offer" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

My script

```js
const supabase = useSupabaseClient();
let country_id = ref(null)
let category_id = ref(null)
let offers = ref(null)

let allOffers = async () => {
    try {
        if (country_id.value === null && category_id.value === null) {
            let { data: offers, pending, refresh, error } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
            return offers
        } else if (country_id.value !== null && category_id.value === null) {
            let { data: offers1, pending1, refresh1, error1 } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
                .eq('country_id', country_id.value)
            let { data: offers2, pending2, refresh2, error2 } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
                .eq('country_id', 1)
            let offers = [...new Set([...offers1, ...offers2])];
            offers = offers.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
                if (!accumulator.find((item) => item.offer_id === current.offer_id)) {
                    accumulator.push(current);
                }
                return accumulator;
            }, []);

            return offers
        } else if (country_id.value === null && category_id.value !== null) {
            let { data: offers, error } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
                .eq(category_id.value.toLowerCase(), true)
            return offers
        } else {
            let { data: offers1, error1 } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
                .eq('country_id', country_id.value)
                .eq(category_id.value.toLowerCase(), true)
            let { data: offers2, error2 } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
                .eq('country_id', 1)
                .eq(category_id.value.toLowerCase(), true)
            let offers = [...new Set([...offers1, ...offers2])];
            offers = offers.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
                if (!accumulator.find((item) => item.offer_id === current.offer_id)) {
                    accumulator.push(current);
                }
                return accumulator;
            }, []);
            return offers
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
offers.value = await allOffers();

function clickCountry(country) {
    country_id.value = country;
    offers.value = allOffers();
}



function clickCategory(category) {
    category_id.value = category;
    offers.value = allOffers();
}
```

I try to use watch, refresh... no success

Comment: How did you try and use `watch`?  the provided code only shows a single console log in each.  Would adding `offers = await allOffers()` to each watch do what you want? Though it seems you could save a step by just calling `allOffers` in both of your functions, `clickCountry` and `clickCategory`.

Comment: Also if `offers` is a ref, then the assignment should always be `offers.value = await allOffers()`

Comment: I try to call all offers in each function but I don’t know how. It’s a variable

Comment: It's a variable that's been assigned a function, **so it's a function**.  An [arrow function](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions-basics) to be precise. It's invoked the same way as a non-arrow function, name + parenthesis, e.g. `allOffers()`

Comment: You actually call allOffers at the very end of your code block `offers = await allOffers();`.  You wrote that.  You called the function. Just repeat that same code wherever else you need to call allOffers...  (I want to point again though, `offers =` should be `offers.value =` because it's a `ref`)

Comment: Thanks. I change offers by offers.value.

Comment: I try to call the function inside clickCountry and clicCategory without success.

Comment: I edit my question with your code advices. I add my template too. Without success. I have blank page when I click on buttons filters

Comment: Oh no.  Why are you copy/pasting all of the code from the function? All you have to do is **call the function**.  You seem to maybe not understand the usage of functions and their purpose, a basic building block of all programs. They are meant to be reusable.  You define it in one place, and call or "invoke" it with a single line of code elsewhere.  I'm afraid whatever task you're trying to accomplish may be too hard, and you should focus on learning basic JavaScript before learning advanced JavaScript frameworks like Vue.  It's too much to teach in a single Stack Overflow answer or comment.

Comment: Yes I understand. I called only function (See code updated) without success. Async / await function isn't ok...

Comment: I just solve my mistake. I have to create async function... and await for the fetch. I answer myself. Thanks very much Yoduh

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yoduh

Just to call function inside async function :-)

```js
const supabase = useSupabaseClient();
let country_id = ref(null)
let category_id = ref(null)
let offers = ref(null)

let allOffers = async () => {
    try {
        if (country_id.value === null && category_id.value === null) {
            let { data: offers, pending, refresh, error } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
            return offers
        } else if (country_id.value !== null && category_id.value === null) {
            let { data: offers1, pending1, refresh1, error1 } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
                .eq('country_id', country_id.value)
            let { data: offers2, pending2, refresh2, error2 } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
                .eq('country_id', 1)
            let offers = [...new Set([...offers1, ...offers2])];
            offers = offers.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
                if (!accumulator.find((item) => item.offer_id === current.offer_id)) {
                    accumulator.push(current);
                }
                return accumulator;
            }, []);

            return offers
        } else if (country_id.value === null && category_id.value !== null) {
            let { data: offers, error } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
                .eq(category_id.value.toLowerCase(), true)
            return offers
        } else {
            let { data: offers1, error1 } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
                .eq('country_id', country_id.value)
                .eq(category_id.value.toLowerCase(), true)
            let { data: offers2, error2 } = await supabase
                .from('offers')
                .select('*')
                .eq('country_id', 1)
                .eq(category_id.value.toLowerCase(), true)
            let offers = [...new Set([...offers1, ...offers2])];
            offers = offers.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
                if (!accumulator.find((item) => item.offer_id === current.offer_id)) {
                    accumulator.push(current);
                }
                return accumulator;
            }, []);
            return offers
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
offers.value = await allOffers();

async function clickCountry(country) {
    country_id.value = country;
    offers.value = await allOffers();
}

async function clickCategory(category) {
    category_id.value = category;
    offers.value = await allOffers();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).